# String extension method in Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

How to use string extension method in linq query:

```
public NewsType GetNewsType(string name)
{
   var newsType = db.NewsTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToFriendlyUrl() ==  
                                              name.ToFriendlyUrl());
   return newsType;
}
```

Above query `x.Name.ToFriendlyUrl()` is not allowed at the minute. Is anyone know how to achieve with it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you post your extension method? That code above looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

Extension methods are indeed allowed in LINQ queries, moreover the [LINQ methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) themselves are implemented as extension methods.

It's quite another issue however, to use extension methods (or most other methods) in LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities queries. Those queries are not actually run in the C# code, but they are treated like expressions that are translated to SQL. I.e.

```
db.News.Where(x => x.Published).Select(x => x.Name)
```

is translated to the SQL Statement

```
Select Name 
From News
Where Published = 1
```

and it's results are returned to the C# code.

Since there is not way to transfer the `ToFriendlyUrl()` method to SQL, your code throws an error.

You have basically, two solutions/workarounds. One is to transform the call to a form could be translated into SQL, e.g. if the `ToFriendlyUrl()` method was just:

```
public static string ToFriendlyURL(this string value)
{
    return value.ToLower();
}
```

you can inline that code in the LINQ call, and that would work. If however, the methods is more complex, than your only solution is to just fetch the data from the base and then process it on the C# side:

```
var newsTypeQuery = db.NewsTypes.Where(x => // other conditions, if any);
var newsTypes = newsTypes.ToList(); //forces execution of the query
                                    // the result is now a C# list
var newsType = newsTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => 
                                 x.Name.ToFriendlyUrl() == name.ToFriendlyUrl());
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
var newsType = db.NewsTypes.FirstOrDefault(
          x => x.Name.ToFriendlyUrl() == name.ToFriendlyUrl());
```

can't be done in Entity Framework. `ToFriendlyUrl` is an extension method. It's something that is in the "client" computer. The query will be executed on the SQL server. The SQL server doesn't have a `ToFriendlyUrl` function.

The "standard" solution is to save in a second column named `FriendlyName` a precalculated version of the `ToFriendlyUrl()`, so your query becomes:

```
var friendlyName = name.ToFriendlyUrl();
var newsType = db.NewsTypes.FirstOrDefault(
          x => x.FriendlyName == friendlyName);
```

Comment: If this only solution then, I will continue with this.

Comment: @coder `"is to save in a second column named"`... It's even written. The advantage is that you can then make an index on that column. The disadvantage is that each time you modify the `Name` column you have to modify the `FriendlyName` column. There are other solutions, like making an equivalent version of `ToFriendlyName()` as an SQL Function, or using the C# "inside" the SQL Server (the SQL CLR integration)... But they are all quite complex (and I'm not even sure you could make a good `ToFriendlyName` function in TSQL. TSQL isn't very strong on string manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `NewsTypes` is an `IQueryable` this is a result of Entity Framework not being able to convert you extension method into SQL (how should it?). Unless you can rewrite your predicate into something that Entity Framework can translate into SQL you will have to perform the query client side:

```
public NewsType GetNewsType(string name)
{
   var newsType = db.NewsTypes.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToFriendlyUrl() == name.ToFriendlyUrl());
   return newsType;
}
```

Notice how `AsEnumerable()` has been added before `FirstOrDefault`. Unfortunately this may pull all the rows returned by `NewsTypes` from the server to client and thus may be quite costly.

Comment: Is this expensive call ?

Comment: @coder: `AsEnumerable` is not expensive, but instead of calling the `FirstOrDefault` that will lead to a "cheap" call on the server side to find the desired row and return it you instead get a `FirstOrDefault` that will pull the rows from the server until the desired row is found. With few rows you may not even notice the difference but with many rows you might suddenly see a noticeable time difference. It depends on your data and environment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try like this

```
public NewsType GetNewsType(string name)
{
   var newsType = db.NewsTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name).ToFriendlyUrl();
   return newsType;
}
```

Comment: But what is the use of **.ToFriendlyUrl()** in your case

Comment: Basically, name comes from url which already been friendly url.

Comment: Then you don't require to use that

Comment: I still need to use this x.Name.ToFriendlyUrl(). See EG.  The parameter "name" is "local-politics". But x.Name is "Local Politics".   So, I have to make x.Name to friendly Url name. Otherwise, they will never match.